# database without operating system

Tags: database, operating-system

Is there any database which can work without any Operating System.

My requirement is, i need to port some code on an embedded device, which runs without OS on a microcontroller. Suggest me the best database or alternate for this scenario.

Comment: Find me a piece of user software that can operate without an operating system.

Comment: I need this for an embedded device program, which runs without OS on a microcontroller

Comment: Does your system has persistent storage?

Comment: yes, additional information now is, that the size of the database has to be less than 150KB.

Comment: DO cdb database requires operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will implement it on an embedded system. If you write your application using C/C++ try use SQLite. There are [SQLite API](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) for C/C++

Comment: Total storage provided to us is only 128 KB, and SQLLite is itself 275KB.

Comment: Do cdb database requires operating system?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple key value store, is my guess. It is better you write a small package for the same as conventional databases may be too heavy for your applications.

BTW most higher end embedded systems (routers/switches) these days seem to be using sqite